# Min number of operations

Tags: algorithm

Given a positive integer N, we are allowed to apply any of the following operations as many times as we want in any order:

First Operation: Add 1 the Given positive integer N; If N is 7, after that operation N becomes 8. If N is 999, after that operation it becomes 1000.

Second operation: choose any occurrence of any digit and replace it by another digit. (475->479, 101 -> 111, 299 -> 199 and so on)

Third operation: add any non-zero digit to the left of the decimal representation of N: 47 -> 247, 9999 -> 49999, 2474 -> 72474 and so on).

Find the minimum number of operations that is needed for changing N to the lucky number.(Lucky numbers are positive integers whose decimal representation contains only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.)

EXAMPLES:

N=25, answer=2

N=46, answer=1

N=99, answer=2

I found this problem while I was trying various problems on LUCKY NUMBER..
I am stuck at this problem...
Please help..

Comment: do you have a time constraint?

Comment: is there any example where solution better than just replacing digits?

Comment: Not exactly ,But the constrains N is 1<=N<=9223372036854775809

Comment: one clarification is 40 be considered as lucky number? given the statement "Lucky numbers are positive integers whose decimal representation contains ONLY the lucky digits 4 and 7", I assume that it's not

Comment: For example you have 407, can we take 0 and add 1 to make it 417 then replace 1 with 4 or 7? or we can only take 0 once and add 1 until it reaches 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "add 1 to the number" and "add any non-zero leading digit to the number" are red herrings.

The minimum number of operations is one per digit in N which is non-lucky. You just change each of the non-4, non-7 digits to either 4 or 7.

Adding a leading digit will never help you because there's no need to make the number longer. Adding 1 *seems* like it could help, but it will only do two things: either it does not carry (when you add to a digit less than 9), in which case a straight replacement can do the same thing, or it carries (when you add to a 9), in which case it's just created one or more non-lucky zeros you're now going to have to "fix" with digit replacement.

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate ": either it does not carry (when you add to a digit less than 9), in which case a straight replacement can do the same thing, or it carries (when you add to a 9), in which case it's just created one or more non-lucky zeros you're now going to have to "fix" with digit replacement."..Or can u please provide Pseudo Code..I am a newbie,finding it a bit difficult to understand.Thanks!

Comment: @Jack Adding one to a 1 is the same as replacing it with a 2. Adding one to a 2 is replacing it with a 3. The only number you'd even *consider* adding one to is a nine... But that would "fix" at most one digit (for instance, 39+1 = 40), and you could "fix" that digit just by directly replacing it. So using the addition will never save you an operation.

Comment: Thanks indeed  Borealid Sir,for clearing my doubts...I understand ur concept well now..

Comment: @ Borealid::I had updated (Edited)a bit ,i hope that makes the doubt  clear regarding the problem statements..Also The Lucky number means,all the digits in a number is either 4 or 7.If a number contains the digit other than this then its not a lucky number

Comment: Sorry the last comment was for  Melvin Protacio

Answer (score 1):

Given the rules, apparently, the answer is the number of digits minus the number of 4 or 7 occurrences. So for example, N=25 you replace each digit with either 4 or 7 taking only one at a time. for 46, you take 6 and replace it with 4 or 7 thus the answer 1.

You can try continuous modulo 10 evaluation to check if the digits are 4 or 7

```
$x = the number
$y = 0; #number of non 4 or 7
while($x>0){
   if($x % 10 != 4 && $x % 10 != 7){
      $y++;
   }
   if($x % 10 == 0){
      $y +=4;
   }
   $x = floor($x/10);
}
```

**Apparently 0 is not replaceable doing some edits**

Answer (score 1):

only second case is important. just take a string and count how many digits are not equal to 4 and 7

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the second operation.........and find the number of digits different from 4 and 7....and thats the answer.....isn't it....:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a greedy solution:

Check all digits in the number and count how many are not 4 or 7
Take the count from the above operation, and see if there's a small count when adding only 1 to the number will get you to Lucky one.

Take the min from both - that's the solution

What's the point in adding leading digits to N ? This will not get you an optimal solution.